# I get an error: could not write bytes: Broken pipe

Tags: boot

Every time I input my password in the Login window and press the ENTER key, I get an error message:

> could not write bytes: Broken pipe

and then quickly return to the Login window. But I can log in as Guest.

I only remember that I have tried to install the ATI display card driver before this situation occurs.

I have tried:

```
sudo dparted
```

to remove the Ubuntu partition and reinstall Ubuntu, but I get same error.

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would just update to the latest Ubuntu version 13.10 with a clean install and then install the AMD drivers with:

sudo apt-get install fglrx

Or from the Ubuntu GUI on the restricted controller tab.

Hope its the fastest and quickest way to solve your problem.

PS: If you are not an Enterprise there is no need to use LTS versions, always update to the latest version.